# APPIUM is not Recognizing the Emulator

Tags: appium

While Running the Script I am not getting any result in the Emulator. But in the APPIUM Server getting the logs as below.

[image]

I Searched the warning getting in the APPIUM server. They said Set the Android sdk path in Environment Variables. I set the ANDROID_HOME in user variables and platform-tools and the tools in the system variables. But still getting this Error.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: what are you getting when you type `echo %ANDROID_HOME%` in the command line?

Comment: I am getting like this.   C:\Users\venu.nagulla.DIT>%ANDROID_HOME%
'D:\androidsdk' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You're using an old version of Appium Desktop tool. Try to add Android SDK path in Appium UI> Android> Advanced tab setting.